# Compiling code using MFC or ATL headers with MinGW on Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, mingw, code-coverage

I'm trying to determine if it is possible to use MinGW to compile code that requires Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC) or Active Templace Libraries (ATL), libraries that come with Microsoft Visual C++ (MSVC).

Some context: My end goal is to be able to generate `gcov` reports on Windows for a C++ tool. The code contains many codepaths which will only be reached if built on Windows (i.e. section guarded by `#ifdef _WIN64`). This means I need to build an `.exe` with `gcc`. The reason I want to do this? I'd like to get a more complete code coverage result by running tests on Windows so that these codepaths can be tested for coverage as well. Is this viable in anyway?

This is what I've tried. Starting small, I've been trying to get this program to build using `MinGW` on Windows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atlstr.h>


int main() {
    CString aCString = CString(_T("A string"));
    _tprintf(_T("%s"), (LPCTSTR)aCString);
}
```

This compiles with MSVC with no hassle. Now, with MinGW: To build I just call `gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage test.cpp  -o test`. However, it fails with the following message:

```
test.cpp:3:10: fatal error: atlstr.h: No such file or directory
 #include <atlstr.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

This is expected of course. I found all the `ATL`, including `atlstr.h`, in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\atlmfc\include`, and copied that all to one of the directories `MinGW` looks for includes. This time it found the header files but a huge list of errors came up which I probably shouldn't include here.

Comment: You don't need to build with g++ to get code coverage data. There are quite a few tools to get you code coverage data with MSVC builds. For one example, [OpenCppCoverage](https://github.com/OpenCppCoverage/OpenCppCoverage).

Comment: Trying to compile/build MFC/ATL code with non-MSVC compliant compilers is probably one  of the fastest routes to insanity! First, the headers are full of non-standard code; second, the linked library (.lib or .dll) files will almost certainly ***not*** be binary compatible with third-party linkers.

Comment: Got it, so I'm wasting my time. Will look into OpenCppCoverage and other alternatives. Thanks guys!